# Topic List and Service List empty

Tags: ros-humble, turtlebot3

I want to use the turtlebot3. Therefor I've installed ROS2 Humble on my PC and the RaspberryPi 4. After the successful bringup of the Turtlebot it looks like this:

[image]

But when I use the command ros2 topic list I only get this as a result:

/parameter_events

/rosout

I think this is also the reason why I cant control the TurtleBot with my  Keyboard.
Do you have any ideas what I've done wrong?

I'm not quite sure what else you could need from me. Feel free to ask.

Comment: Please paste console output as *text* and not as a screenshot. Images are not text-searchable.

Comment: In your output text, it shows you shutdown the turtlebot nodes with a ctrl-c command. If you are trying to list the available topics after this, then you won't see any. Some other important questions: can you run the keyboard teleop from another terminal logged in to the Raspberry Pi? Do you know if your router supports multicast?

Comment: I‘ve let it run for multiple minutes, but then I stopped it with control-c because nothing happened. What should I do instead? 
I can look after my router when I‘m at home. Forgive me for the mistakes, this is my first post.

Comment: There's a lot of missing information that could help diagnose what and where your problem lies, and I understand as a beginner you don't know what that information is. First, as requested, update your post to have text and not a screenshot. Second, is the console output from the laptop or the Rasberry Pi, and is that device the one connected to the Turtlebot hardware? Third, where are you running the `ros2 topic list` command (meaning which computer and are you trying in a new console window)? Fourth, if you are using separate computers, can they communicate (`ping`) with each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the logs, you just launch the bringup nodes, so the robot was waiting the commands.
You should open a new terminal and launch the teleop launch. You can follow [this guide](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/basic_operation/#basic-operation), be sure to let the bringup terminal open and working.
To see that bringup works, you can look in the same guide the [previous page](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/bringup/#bringup)